# Nunit --Data insert test issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to Nunit testing.
I am trying to write test method for a method which inserts data in Database.

My code is like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NUnit.Framework;
using MBT.Entities;


[TestFixture]
public class TagStoreTest
{
    private Tag testTag;

    public TagStoreTest()
    {
      this.testTag = new Tag();
    }

[Test]
public void InsertTagTest()
{
    TagStore tagSt = new TagStore();
    bool isInserted = tagSt.InsertTag(this.testTag);

    Assert.IsTrue(isInserted);
}


[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    this.testTag.TagName = "testtagthroughNunit";
}

     [TearDown]
     public void TearDown()
     {

     }

 }
```

And actual TagStore code is like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MBT.Datastore;
using System.Data;

using MBT.Entities;


  public class TagStore
 {
   private string _connectionString = string.Empty;

   public TagStore()
   {
    this._connectionString = SqlHelper.GetConnectionString();
    }


    public bool InsertTag(Tag tag)
   {
     bool isInserted = false;

     using (DatabaseHelper helper = Utility.DbHelper)
     {
        int tagsAdded = helper
            .AddInputParameter("@Tag", tag.TagName)
            .AddInputParameter("@ParentTagId", tag.ParentTagId)
            .ExecuteNonQuery("Proc_InsertTags", CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        if (tagsAdded > 0)
        {
            isInserted = true;
        }
    }
    return isInserted;
 }
}
```

When i run test i get error: `TagStoreTest.InsertTagTest:
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

And code line `TagStore tagSt = new TagStore();` is highlighted in red.

I dont know whats going wrong because my project builds successfully but i get error when i run test.

Comment: There's usually a stacktrace when you run NUNIT. Also, does SqlHelper.GetConnectionString() has any external dependencies you're not correctly instantiating while unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your TagStore constructor is setting connectionString member. Try to debug what is returned by

```
SqlHelper.GetConnectionString();
```

Your SqlHelper could be playing tricks.

I also suggest try using some sort of mocking technique to isolate tests. For e.g. you can mock the SqlHelper object which always returns a  desired connectionstring. There are plenty of framework out there for e.g. Moq.

Comment: Yes.. you are right...its problem with SqlHelper.GetConnectionString(); only...i checked stackstrace and it is also pointing towards SqlHelper.GetConnectionString();, However When i tried debugging code I could get proper connection string... Code in SQLHelper is like :   public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString();
        },  Only problem could be configuration manager but i have added reference in class library.

Comment: This is the reason why you need to isolate your tests. Initially you were testing your business code (TagStore) but now you are dealing with the connectionstring issue which is diverting your effort from the job in hand (not saying you should perm. ignore connectionstring issue). I strongly suggest looking at one of the Mock framework and implement this in your unit test. Mock your conneciton object and get Your business code tested. Once you done with your BusinessCode then resolve the issue with connectionstring. Idea is resolve one problem at a time :)